# The selected option must shown after the function of onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdowns, just like the title.. The selected option must shown after the function of onchange meaning when it automatically refreshes the selected option must stay and show the selected options . The problem is when I select an option from the 2nd dropdown which has onchange function it refreshes and it gets back to the default option.

Here's the code

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
     <h1 class="page-header">
      BRANCHES
     </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <a class="btn btn-default bad-marg" href="index.php?act=abr" role="button">Add Branch</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div id="form">
       <form action="func_vbrs.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="bl" class="control-label col-xs-3"><p class="left">Branch</p></label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <div class="req">
       <select name="bid" class='form-control'>
        <option value='' default style='color:gray;'>Branch</option>
         <?php
          include_once "config.php";

          $sql="select branchID, b, bl from branch where b!='HOK'";
          $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($bid, $b, $bl);
          $stmt->store_result();
          
          while($stmt->fetch()){
           echo '<option value="'.$bid.'">'.$b.'-'.$bl.'</option>';
          } 
         ?>
       </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cat" class="control-label col-xs-3"><p class="left">Category</p></label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
       <div class="req">
        <select name="brcat" class="form-control"  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
         <option value="" default style="color:gray;">Category</option>
         <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
         <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
         <option value="Stock Transfer">Stock Transfer</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    </div>
    </div>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the 2nd drop down is category, If a user already selects an option after the automatic refresh or onchange function, it gets back to default option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross check against post on page load, and add a `selected` tag appropriately.  There are more elegant solutions with less bulky code if you use a loop to create your options, but that's another question.

```
<?PHP
    if (!empty($_POST['brcat'])){
        $selected_item = $_POST['brcat'];
    } else { $selected_item = Null; }

    function selcheck($item1, $item2){
        if ($item1 == $item2){
            $ret = " selected=\"selected\" ";
        } else {
            $ret = "";
        }
        return($ret);
    }

?>

<select name="brcat" class="form-control"  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="" default style="color:gray;">Category</option>

<?PHP
$sel = selcheck("Stock",$selected_item);
?>
<option value="Stock"<?=$sel?>>Stock</option>

<?PHP
$sel = selcheck("Sales",$selected_item);
?>
<option value="Sales"<?=$sel?>>Sales</option>

<?PHP
$sel = selcheck("Stock Transfer",$selected_item);
?>
<option value="Stock Transfer"<?=$sel?>>Stock Transfer</option>
```